# cuda-gdb sees only one least capable device from four CUDA-capable devices available

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, cuda-gdb

There are four CUDA-capable devices available:

```
teslabot$ ./deviceQuery | grep -i "device [0-9]\|capability"
Device 0: "Tesla C2050 / C2070"
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    2.0
Device 1: "Tesla C2050 / C2070"
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    2.0
Device 2: "GeForce GTX 295"
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    1.3
Device 3: "GeForce GTX 295"
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    1.3
```

`cuda-dbg` sees only one of them:

```
teslabot$ cuda-gdb vector_add
NVIDIA (R) CUDA Debugger
4.0 release
Portions Copyright (C) 2007-2011 NVIDIA Corporation
GNU gdb 6.6
Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
[...]
(cuda-gdb) break vector_add_gpu
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400ddb: file vector_add.cu, line 7.
(cuda-gdb) run
[...]
(cuda-gdb) info cuda devices
  Dev Description SM Type SMs Warps/SM Lanes/Warp Max Regs/Lane Active SMs Mask
*   0       gt200   sm_13  30       32         32           128 0x00000001
```

I have checked that code build with `-gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20` compiles without errors on said machine, and when compiled for `sm_20` then using `printf` in CUDA kernel works correctly.

How can I make `cuda-gdb` see all devices (perhaps except one used for graphics... though in said case I am logging remotely via SSH), or at least one Tesla / sm_20 device?

---

When following advise in [Michael Foukarakis response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8819249/46058) by setting `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` environment variable to contain only "0,1" i.e. make visible only Teslas, I get the following error after running `info cuda devices`:

```
(cuda-gdb) info cuda devices
fatal:  All CUDA devices are used for X11 and cannot be used while debugging. (error code = 24)
```

How to check which devices are used by X11 (X.Org), and how to make X Window System to use GeForce and not Tesla?

Comment: `info cuda devices` should only show the card or cards running kernels or with valid contexts held by the current debugging session. `info cuda system` should show whether all the cards are visible or not. Note that there isn't any guarantee of enumeration consistancy between the driver (so what nvidia-smi or cuda-gdb shows) and the API. The `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` mechanism and/or driver compute mode status is the best way to steer code onto the hardware you want.

Comment: `cuda-gdb` version 4.0 (from CUDA SDK 4.0.17) does not have **`system`** info: `info cuda system` results in *"Unrecognized option: 'system'."*

Answer (score 2):

Can you make sure the `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` environment variable contains all the devices you want to be used, such as:

```
$ ./deviceQuery -noprompt | egrep "^Device"
Device 0: "Tesla C2050"
Device 1: "Tesla C1060"
Device 2: "Quadro FX 3800"
```

By setting the variable you can make only a subset of them visible to the runtime:

```
$ export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="0,2"
$ ./deviceQuery -noprompt | egrep "^Device"
Device 0: "Tesla C2050"
Device 1: "Quadro FX 3800"
```

Comment: When I used `export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="0,1"` (i.e. only CUDA devices with capability 2.0 - Teslas) I get the following error when trying to run `info cuda devices`: **fatal:  All CUDA devices are used for X11 and cannot be used while debugging. (error code = 24)**. So how to make X11 not use Teslas but Quadros for display?

Comment: @JakubNarębski: The CUDA driver has the facility to limit or prohibit the use of any given card via the "compute mode" setting. You can use the SDK `deviceQuery` or `nvidia-smi` to check whether the Telsas are set to compute exclusive or compute prohibited. That could be the source of the problem.

Comment: @talonmies: How to change "compute mode" setting, then (on Linux with X.Org)?